# Is there a Xcode shortcut to type all the enum cases in a switch?

Tags: xcode, enums, switch-statement

supposing I have this enum:

```
enum Test {
    case test1
    case test2
    case test3
}
```

I would like to know if there is a shortcut or a command with Xcode that would quickly write this:

```
switch test {
case .test1:
    /// ...
case .test2:
    /// ...
case .test3:
    /// ...
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is not available in `Xcode 12.5` via autocomplete as you type. However you can use the suggestion - "Add missing cases" to achieve this.

This is available via autocomplete as you type in current `Xcode 13 beta`. [This tweet](https://twitter.com/twostraws/status/1402139628254138368) shows a nice GIF of this feature in action -

[image]

Comment: This seems to only work if `color` is passed directly into switch. For some reason Xcode fails to suggest any autocompleting when `color` is nested inside a struct, like `switch someStruct.color` would not offer to autocomplete enum cases.